# How to handle multi-select boxes in a zend framework form?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Just wondering how it works and how to handle the information.

Let's say I have a form like this:

```
$multi = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('users');
$multi->setMultiOptions(array(
    //'option value' => 'option label'
    '21' => 'John Doe',
    '22' => 'Joe Schmoe',
    '23' => 'Foobar Bazbat'
));
$form->addElement($multi);
```

If a user selects one, or multiple values from a multi-select box...

- How do I get the value that the user selected?
- Does it return in array? or what?
- How can I tell how many items the user selected?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a multi select element like this one:

```
$multi = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('users');
$multi->setMultiOptions(array(
    //'option value' => 'option label'
    '21' => 'John Doe',
    '22' => 'Joe Schmoe',
    '23' => 'Foobar Bazbat'
));
$form->addElement($multi);
```

You can get the values of the element like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new MyForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {

            $values = $form->getValues();
            $users = $values['users']; //'users' is the element name
            var_dump $users;
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

`$users` will contain an array of the values that have been selected:

```
array(
    0 => '21',
    1 => '23'
)
```

Comment: I am doing almost same thing but getting only one selected option even selecting multiple. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052512/zend-multiselect-element-is-posting-only-one-selected-values

Answer (score 3):

```
$form->getElement('name')->getValue()
```

will return the value of $_POST['name']. You can make

```
$_POST['name']
```

be an array by defining the name of the element with brackets at the end. So in this case, 'name[]'. In the Zend Framework, use an element that extends

```
Zend_Form_Element_Multi
```

Please see: http://www.framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.multiselect

For example:

```
$multi = $form->createElement('multiselect', 'name[]');
$multi->setMultiOptions($options);
$form->addElement($multi);

if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
    $userSelectedOptions = $form->getElement('name')->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See the answer from brad. The especial part is the name of the element

```
$multi = $form->createElement('multiselect', 'name[]');
```

if you call the element with squares it will be handled as an array by the browser (not a zf behavior). Otherwise you'll get only the first selected element

Answer (score 0):

Also one remark, maybe useful for someone here (I spent some time to get it):

If you are creating your own multi checkbox element, you must extend `Zend_Form_Element_MultiCheckbox` , because validation does not work correctly, when you are extending just `Zend_Form_Element_Multi`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to others: I found on Zend Framework 1.12 that if you don't pass the multi element a name ending in [] it throws an error in Zend Form.

E.g.

`$this->addElement('multiselect', 'somename'); // throws error`

while:

`$this->addElement('multiselect', 'somename[]'); // works`

Answer (score 0):

use this to handle multi-select boxes in a zend framework form bro :

```
    $multi->setAttrib('multiple', 'multiple');
```

so it will be like this in your own code:

```
    $multi = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('users');
    $multi->setAttrib('multiple', 'multiple');
    $multi->setMultiOptions(array(
        //'option value' => 'option label'
        '21' => 'John Doe',
        '22' => 'Joe Schmoe',
        '23' => 'Foobar Bazbat'
    ));
    $form->addElement($multi);
```